# CHECK: Show that $N_G(aHa^{-1})=aN_G(H)a^{-1}$ for $a \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that $N_G(aHa^{-1})=aN_G(H)a^{-1}$ for $a \in G$.

Hint: When working this problem, I found that in showing the two sets equal I had to be extremely careful. Try not to make big jumps. At one point I had to let $x=aga^{-1}$ for $g \in G$.

By definition, $N_G(H) =\{g\in G: gHg^{-1}=H\}$. So 
$$ aN_G(H)a^{-1} =\{g\in G: agHg^{-1}a^{-1}=aHa^{-1}=H\} =\{g\in G: agH(ag)^{-1}=aHa^{-1}=H\} =N_G(aHa^{-1}) $$

Did I make a big leap?

Comment: Your work doesn't quite make sense to me, though perhaps it does to others. In general, I think the best strategy for showing two sets are equal is to show each mutually contains the other.

Comment: Admittedly, my group theory is rusty, but on your first centered line, isn't $aN_{G}(H)a^{-1}$ the set $\{aga^{-1} : gHg^{-1} = H\}$ (where $a, g \in G$ is taken for granted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: suppose $g \in N_{G}(aHa^{-1})$. Then $gaHa^{-1}g^{-1} = aHa^{-1}$, which implies $a^{-1}gaHa^{-1}g^{-1}a = H$, i.e. $(a^{-1}ga)H(a^{-1}ga)^{-1} = H$. Hence, $a^{-1}ga \in N_{G}(H)$, so $g = ag'a^{-1}$ for some $g' \in N_{G}(H)$, i.e. $g \in aN_{G}(H)a^{-1}$. Therefore, $N_{G}(aHa^{-1}) \subset aN_{G}(H)a^{-1}$.

Now suppose $g \in aN_{G}(H)a^{-1}$. Then $g = ag'a^{-1}$, where $g' \in N_{G}(H)$, so $g' = a^{-1}ga$. Now note that $g'H(g')^{-1} = H$. Can you take it from here to show that this implies $g \in N_{G}(aHa^{-1})$? (It may help to look above.)

Feel free to comment if you need further suggestions!

Comment: Oh ok. I was on the right track at least idea wise. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!